# homomorphism of graded modules

Tags: commutative-algebra

This is a little exercise problem from Peeva's book on graded syzygies.

Let $\phi:N\to T$ be a homomorphism of graded $R$-modules. If $f=f_1+\cdots+f_n\in N$ and $f_i$ are its homogeneous components, then $\phi(f_i)$ are homogeneous components of $\phi(f)$  (in the context $R$ is a quotient of a polynomial ring by a graded ideal.)

It shouldn't be hard, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the grading of $T$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, a morphism of graded modules maps $N_k$ into $T_k$ for each $k$, which is to say that it maps homogeneous elements to homogeneous elements of the same degree. In particular, it preserves the homogeneous components.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why it's "by definition". We know what module homomorphisms are and how graded modules are defined. Shouldn't this "definition" be something we can proof from those knowledge?

Comment: @D.Huang: Often mathematicians say "homomorphism of graded modules" when they mean for the map to be a "graded homomorphism" and not just a "homomorphism" whose domain and codomain happen to be graded.

Comment: @Jim I see. I should've read the definition more carefully. This problem is obvious then. Thanks!